# Is there a way to avoid repeating types in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Let's say I have an enum:

```js
enum AlertAction {
  RESET = "RESET",
  RESEND = "RESEND",
  EXPIRE = "EXPIRE",
}
```

I want to create multiple actions, as shown below:

```js
type Action<T> = {
  type: T;
  payload: string;
};

type ActionType =
  | Action<Action.RESET>
  | Action<Action.RESEND>
  | Action<Action.EXPIRE>;
```

In `ActionType`, I wrote the code Action<enum> multiple times.

Is there a way to not repeat writing Action<enum>?

Answer (score 1):

It's straightforward :

```
type ActionType = Action<AlertAction>
```